# Python regex to extract date pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a sentence of the form(keyword followed by left parenthesis followed by any string followed by 2 dates separated by a hyphen):

```
Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi (/ˈɡɑːndi, ˈɡæn-/; Hindustani: [ˈmoːɦənd̪aːs ˈkərəmtʃənd̪ ˈɡaːnd̪ʱi]; 2 October 1869 – 30 January 1948) was the preeminent leader of the Indian independence movement in British-ruled India.
```

I need to extract the birth date(2 October 1869) and date of death(30 January 1948) from this sentence using regex.I have written regex for extracting date patterns.

```
date_pattern="(\d{1,2}(\s|-|/)?(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May?|June?|July?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(t(ember)?)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?|\d{1,2})(\s|-|/)?\d{2,4})"
```

I need to extract sentences of the form as above and separately print the date of birth and date of death.

Comment: Is this a "debug my code for me" -type question, or is there a specific part of the problem that you're struggling with? Will the dates be in many different formats or only a specific format? Do you have to worry about upper and lower case?

Comment: Where are you stuck, and where didn't the [prior answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+regex+date) solve your problem?

Comment: If the input format is as regular as the example in your question, you don't need regular expressions at all. Each piece of information is delimted by parentheses and semi-colons, so you can use `str.split` to get the parts and then `datetime.strptime` to parse the dates.

Comment: Hi, I need to match  whole sentences of the fom: keyword(gandhi) followed by left parenthesis followed by any string followed by 2 dates separated by a hyphen and then extract the dates. This is a sample sentence. There can be many other dates in the sentence. So i need to extract sentence that satisfy above criteria and then extract birth and death dates

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

text = '''Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi (/ˈɡɑːndi, ˈɡæn-/; Hindustani: [ˈmoːɦənd̪aːs ˈkərəmtʃənd̪ ˈɡaːnd̪ʱi]; 2 October 1869 – 30 January 1948) was the preeminent leader of the Indian independence movement in British-ruled India.'''
birth, death = re.findall(r'\d+[ \d\w]+', text)
print(birth)
print(death)
```

out:

```
2 October 1869 
30 January 1948
```

Comment: Hi,keyword followed by left parenthesis followed by any string followed by 2 dates separated by a hyphen

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
date_pattern="(\d{1,2}(?:\s|-|/)?(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May?|June?|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:t(?:ember)?)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?|\d{1,2})(?:\s|-|/)?\d{2,4})"

bio = "Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi (/ˈɡɑːndi, ˈɡæn-/; Hindustani: [ˈmoːɦənd̪aːs ˈkərəmtʃənd̪ ˈɡaːnd̪ʱi]; 2 October 1869 – 30 January 1948) was the preeminent leader of the Indian independence movement in British-ruled India."

matches = re.findall(date_pattern, bio)
if matches and len(matches) > 1:
   born = matches[0]
   died = matches[1]
   print("Born:", born)
   print("Died:", died)
```